# How to give semantic zoom in windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing an app in which I want to add semantic zoom for languages. I used blank app...
I used simple mode not used grid or split template. In blank template, how may I use semantic zoom. Don't give me MSDN link.??
Language VB.net & C#
using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample by MS.
Hope it will help.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e